# *.XmlSerializers.dll not seen by my app

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I migrated my build machine from VS2010 on Windows XP to VS2012 on Windows 7.

Part of my build step was calling sgen.exe to generate XmlSerializers for my app. This worked well previously, but since I'm building on the new configuration, my application does not see the DLL anymore. An exception is thrown that the XmlSerializer could not be resolved.

However, the DLL is still being generated and sits in the same folder as my application executable.

Any suggestions why it cannot be loaded anymore in the new situation?

Comment: does it work if you register the dll to the gac?

Comment: don't have experience with registering in the gac. But that shouldn't be neccesary..?

Comment: no it should not be but was just ment as an experiment. An example would be a batch file like: regasm asembly.dlll /tlb:asembly.tlb
gacutil.exe /i asembly.dll

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to see why it doesn't like that DLL.